# Using `boost::lexical_cast` causes error "identifier "__float128" is undefined"

Tags: c++, boost, casting

In my current C++ project I want to make use of `boost::lexical_cast` as follows:

```
namespace lex = boost::lexical_cast;
std::vector< std::string > line_sep;
// ...
int dim_n = lex::lexical_cast<int>(line_sep[0]);
```

However, when adding those lines of code, I run into the following error:

```
boost/math/policies/policy.hpp", line 818: error:                                                                                                                      
          identifier "__float128" is undefined
struct precision<BOOST_MATH_FLOAT128_TYPE, Policy>
                 ^
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem? Just in case I added the output of `g++ -v` below:

```
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/4.8.1-64 --enable-static --enable-shared --with-gmp=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/4.8.1-64 --with-mpfr=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/4.8.1-64 --with-mpc=/cadappl_sde/ictools/gcc/4.8.1-64 --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --disable-werror --disable-nls --enable-threads=posix --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libada --enable-plugin --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I use Boost Version 1.59.

Comment: "gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)" - I suggest you look into [devtoolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_toolset/7/html/7.0_release_notes/dts7.0_release) and get yourself a modern (supported) compiler.

Comment: I believe __float128 is a gnu extension, so compile with `--std=gnu++11`.